# Project find does not display text

Tags: xcode

After doing a project level find the lower pane displays the text: "No Editor" and nothing else.  This just started happening a couple of days ago.  I had updated to the latest iPhone Xcode build, this may have had something to do with it.

I just deleted the Developer directory and did a re-install of Xcode 3.2.1. that did not help.

How an I get this to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode preferences were corrupt.  ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist

Restored from TimeMachine and all is fine.

I suspect that the latest Xcode beta form the iPhone portal may have aused the corruption.